# React, <USE> .. xlinkHref no longer works with Chrome v71

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, svg, shadow-dom

I've had a React SVG component that had been working fine for the last year... In my SVG component, I have a  tag like so:

```
    <use
      innerRef={(ref) => { this.arcRef.icon = ref; }}
      xlinkHref={this.props.xlinkHref}
      width="10"
      height="10"
      x="240.462"
      y="138"
    />
```

This is rendering in the dom like so:

```
<use class="sc-dTLGrV fEJmAu" href="#item-2" width="40px" height="40px" x="240.462" y="138" data-svg-origin="240.462 138" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,38,-26.5)" style="opacity: 1;"></use>
```

Chrome recently updated to v71 and now this is no longer working. In the [Chrome v71 release notes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/12/nic71) it mentions "Chrome 71 was updated to support the Shadow DOM v1 spec"

In the DOM I see the following inside the `<use>` tag:

`#shadow-root (closed)`

I believe use can no longer find the `#item-2` element on the page even though it is there...

Any ideas on how I can get this working again?

Comment: What is `#item-2`?  Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and it was because I had ID's conflicting.
It worked previously on all Chrome versions but not on 71.

Try to resolve these conflicts if any.

Comment: @reviewers, This answer, while far from being perfect **does try to answer the question**. Vote to close the question instead, which is missing an MCVE.